# Angular JS emptying form input field from controller when using ng-model

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I have a really simple form with a couple of input fields. Here's one:

```
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="signInData.firstName" placeholder="">
            </label>
```

When I submit the form and it returns true from the AJAX request, I want to simply empty the input field but it's not working. I may be missing something simple..

Here's my controller code where I'm attempting to empty:

```
        $scope.signInData.firstName = '';
```

This is emptying the model from the scope, which I can see because I am console logging the scope object, but it just doesn't empty the value.

I've Googled for a while and seen things like the $setPristine method etc, but none of this is working either.

EDIT

```
    $http({
      url: 'sign_in_app',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {'firstName': signInData.firstName}
    }).then(function(response) {
      if(response.data.response == 'error'){
        $scope.errorSignIn = 'Sorry, there was an error signing in.';
      }else{
        $scope.errorSignIn = null;
        $scope.signInData.firstName = '';
        $scope.signInForm = null;
      }
    }
```

EDIT - the form

```
    <form ng-submit="signIn(signInData)" id="signInForm" name="signInForm">
        <div ng-bind-html="errorSignIn" class="center error"></div>
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="signInData.firstName" placeholder="">
            </label>

            <label class="item">
              <button class="button button-full button" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </label>
         </div>
     </form>
```

EDIT 3 - UPDATED HTTP CALL

```
    $http({
      url: '/sign_in/sign_in_app',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {'firstName': $scope.signInData.firstName, 'lastName': $scope.signInData.lastName}
    }).then(function(response) {
      if(response.data.response == 'error'){
        $scope.errorSignIn = 'Sorry, there was an error signing in.';
      }else{
        $scope.errorSignIn = null;
        $scope.signInData.firstName = '';
        $scope.signInForm = null;
      }

    }
```

Comment: Show full code context where you reset model

Comment: Why are you passing `signInData` on your ng-submit and what are you doing with that object? Is it possible that a shadow copy is being created somehow?

Comment: you can't pass signInData like that. you have to pass like $scope.signInData.firstName

Comment: @Akhlesh Why pass anything at all? The value is already updated in the scope through the use of ng-model and two-way data binding.

Comment: @Lex Yes value is already updated but how how would you send data to server? either send whole scope object or some selected values....right?

Comment: The form also contains a last name field. I'm passing in the whole signInData object which contains both the first and last name. I thought this may be a cleaner way of handling it. The ngSubmit passes in this object

Comment: @Akhlesh I'm talking about passing the data to the controller. It's already there via $scope, ng-model, and two-way data binding. From there you can use the $scope properties to pass whatever information to your service.

Comment: Oh i got you...sorry my bad. yes there is no need to pass anything.

Comment: @JamesG Try this: remove the signInData from the ng-submit, alter your signIn scope method to no longer need that, use the $scope.signInData object to set all the values for your $http call (which, by the way, should probably be in a service to keep your controller more clean and follow typical Angular design patterns) and then see if you still have the issue where your form inputs are not being cleared.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. @Lex I did originally try it that way (as I've just put in my EDIT 3) but for some reason the data doesn't send to the server this way. I'm inspecting the console and the form data {} is empty..

Comment: @JamesG Is the $http() call inside your Angular controller?

Comment: Yes it is, within the $scope.signIn function (which is called on ngSubmit() of the form)

Comment: Ok you were right! Sorry, I forgot to take something out but using the values from thr scope object directly in the http call worked. THANKS!

Comment: Cool. I'll move my comment to an answer then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: remove the `signInData` from the `ng-submit`, alter your `$scope.signIn()` method to no longer need that, use the `$scope.signInData` object to set all the values for your `$http` call (which, by the way, should probably be in a service to keep your controller more clean and follow typical Angular design patterns) and then see if you still have the issue where your form inputs are not being cleared.

My suspicion is that because you are passing `signInData` from that point forward you start operating on a copy of the scope object and that is why clearing properties is not behaving like you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

`$setPristine` does not clean up the input fields. You can try using 
`$scope.signInData = {};` after submitting the form